# Google Play Services not Available in my new Model Tablet

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I Bought my new Datawind Ubislate 10 NS Tablet. I didn't receive GCM push notification in my Tablet. So i checked for google play services in Settings>Apps but i cannot find Google play services. GCM push notification will work without Google play services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GCM push notification will work without Google play services?

No. GCM (now Firebase Cloud Messaging) only works on a Google Play ecosystem device.

Answer (score 1):

No, GCM push notification will not work without Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing google play services apk from unofficial source like [this](https://www.androidpit.com/install-google-play-services-apk), [this](http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/google-play-services-apk-latest-version-download/) and check if it works.